# IIS 7.5 Lock my DLL after many request

Tags: c#, iis, dll, webserver

I have a big problem, i deployed on my web server IIS 7.0 a custom DLL that provide some data (exaclty one row per day up to maximun 365 row). This dll work fine for about 6 or 7 hours, after that IIS lock this DLL and no data return in my front-end. If i do a iisreset and app pool recycle all back to work correctly untill next dll lock. In my Application Pool have setup Regular Time Interval to recycle but iis lock equally my DLL. I'm desperate anybody can suggest me any solution??

Comment: Check for the use of mutexe's and synchronization objects, as my experience those have problems with IIS, also check for static objects.

Comment: do not use anything like mutex or synchronization, i use only TimeSpan or DateTime instance for some date/time calculation.

Comment: Does the doll require IIS to function?

Comment: Dll it's write in C and used in asp.net means DllImport directive